# Sorting by count using pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, yelp

I'm trying to print the top 11 states, the biggest city in each state and the business count for each state. For some reason I am having trouble printing the business count for the state, only getting the count for the city.

Here is the code I am having trouble with

`dun=df_busSelected.groupBy("state","city").count().orderBy("count",ascending=False).limit(11).show(truncate=False)`

```
 +-----+----------+-----+ 
|state|city |count| 
+-----+----------+-----+ 
|NV |Las Vegas |29361| 
|ON |Toronto |18904| 
|AZ |Phoenix |18764| 
|NC |Charlotte |9507 | 
|AZ |Scottsdale|8837 | 
|AB |Calgary |7735 | 
|PA |Pittsburgh|7016 | 
|QC |Montréal |6449 | 
|AZ |Mesa |6080 | 
|NV |Henderson |4892 | 
|AZ |Tempe |4550 | 
+-----+----------+-----+
```

Comment: please show some data an what could be the expected result. With an example, it is always clearer.

Comment: For the code in the body here is the result:

+-----+----------+-----+
|state|city      |count|
+-----+----------+-----+
|NV   |Las Vegas |29361|
|ON   |Toronto   |18904|
|AZ   |Phoenix   |18764|
|NC   |Charlotte |9507 |
|AZ   |Scottsdale|8837 |
|AB   |Calgary   |7735 |
|PA   |Pittsburgh|7016 |
|QC   |Montréal  |6449 |
|AZ   |Mesa      |6080 |
|NV   |Henderson |4892 |
|AZ   |Tempe     |4550 |
+-----+----------+-----+

Comment: The problem is those values are the count for businesses within the city and I need the count for the state. I can't just exclude the city though because my table must show the name of the largest city as well.

Comment: @AndrewKehl this is the expected behaviour for a groupBy(state, city). If you want both counts create another groupBy(state) Spark statement and finally join them based on state.

Comment: How would I go about joining them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need to do:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_busSelected = spark.createDataFrame([("NV", "Las Vegas",29361),("ON", "Toronto" ,18904),("AZ", "Phoenix",18764),("NC", "Charlotte",9507),("AZ", "Scottsdale",8837),("AB", "Calgary",7735),("PA", "Pittsburgh",7016),("QC", "Montréal",6449),("AZ", "Mesa",6080),("NV", "Henderson",4892),("AZ", "Tempe",4550)]).toDF("state", "city", "count")

df_busSelected.withColumn("city_total_business", struct(col("count"), col("city")))\
     .groupBy("state")\
     .agg(sort_array(collect_set(col("city_total_business")), False)[0].name("top_city"))\
     .withColumn("city", col("top_city").getItem("city"))\
     .withColumn("count", col("top_city").getItem("count"))\
     .drop("top_city")\
     .show()
```

Prints out

```
+-----+----------+-----+
|state|      city|count|
+-----+----------+-----+
|   AZ|   Phoenix|18764|
|   QC|  Montréal| 6449|
|   NV| Las Vegas|29361|
|   NC| Charlotte| 9507|
|   PA|Pittsburgh| 7016|
|   ON|   Toronto|18904|
|   AB|   Calgary| 7735|
+-----+----------+-----+
```

This returns the city with the highest count for each state. It's easy now to sort and do what you want with them.

Please rate my answer if you like it.